# How to get the section when press a button in my custom section header view in tableview

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    var sectionHeaderView = NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("PlanCellSectionHeader", owner: nil, options: nil).first as PlanCellSectionHeader!
    sectionHeaderView.addBtn.addTarget(self, action: "didPressAdd:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
    return sectionHeaderView
}
func didPressAdd(sender:UIButton) {
    var point = sender.convertPoint(CGPointZero, toView: self.tableView!)
    var indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForRowAtPoint(point)
    //won't work
    println("section = \(indexPath?.section)")
}
```

And it turns out that the indexPath is nil, and when using tags added to each section header, i found that others say it would crash if we delete sections in runtime, so any helps?

Comment: OK, i found that TAG should work, 'cause I should reload tableview's data if i delete section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `tag` property in button class. It's easiest way to achieve this, but probably not the best.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    var sectionHeaderView = NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("PlanCellSectionHeader", owner: nil, options: nil).first as PlanCellSectionHeader!
    sectionHeaderView.addBtn.addTarget(self, action: "didPressAdd:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
    sectionHeaderView.addBtn.tag = section
    return sectionHeaderView
}
func didPressAdd(sender:UIButton) {
    println("section = \(sender.tag)")
}
```

I prefer create subclass for header view. Then you can handle index and action on button press.

```
class HeaderView: UIView {
  var section: Int
  @IBAction func buttPressed() {
     println("section = \(section))
  }
}
```

Comment: thank u very much, and this is my first question ^ ^